# how do I use Python requests to api.trafikinfo.trafikverket.se/API?

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests

I am trying to use an API from trafikverket.se to get current air temperatures in Python. I've registered an account and got a key to use for my request. But even though I am trying their example code I can not get it to work.

[API request documentation trafikverket.se](https://api.trafikinfo.trafikverket.se/API/TheRequest)

my python code:

```
import requests

data = """
<REQUEST>
      <LOGIN authenticationkey="8c981e556c........." />
      <QUERY objecttype="WeatherStation" schemaversion="1">
            <FILTER>
                  <EQ name="Name" value="Högakustenbron Topp" />
            </FILTER>
            <INCLUDE>Measurement.Air.Temp</INCLUDE>
            <INCLUDE>Measurement.MeasureTime</INCLUDE>
      </QUERY>
</REQUEST>
"""

#data = data.encode('utf8')
print(requests.post('https://api.trafikinfo.trafikverket.se/v2/data.json', data=data).json())
```

I have tried it with and without the encode to utf8 since I found someone else that had a similar problem and that solved it for them. I only get a strange response:

`{'RESPONSE': {'RESULT': [{'ERROR': {'SOURCE': 'Request', 'MESSAGE': 'Header Content-Type  is invalid.'}}]}}`

if i use the response query on their test console i get the correct response:

```
{
  "RESPONSE": {
    "RESULT": [
      {
        "WeatherStation": [
          {
            "Measurement": {
              "MeasureTime": "2022-11-11T15:40:00.000+01:00",
              "Air": {
                "Temp": 11.3
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation you linked to, it looks like they require a `Content-Type` header (translated to English):

> Content-Type
>
> As of version 2, the POST call must have one of the following values ​​in the Content-Type header:
>
> ```
> application/xml
> text/xml
> text/plain (triggers no CORS preflight, more info here .)
> ```

Original:

> Content-Type
>
> Från och med version 2 måste POST-anropet ha någon av följande värde i
> Content-Type headern:
>
> ```
> application/xml
> text/xml
> text/plain (triggar ingen CORS preflight, mer info finns här.)
> ```

I would suggest trying the following:

```py
print(requests.post('https://api.trafikinfo.trafikverket.se/v2/data.json', data=data, headers={'Content-Type': 'text/xml'}).json())
```

If `text/xml` does not work, then I would suggest trying `application/xml` or `text/plain` in its place.